# Does grails command requires internet connectivity

Tags: grails

I am new to grails. Can anyone please let me know if is it necessary to have internet connectivity to execute commands , such as grails clean and grails compile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. and Yes. Here is why:

`grails clean` doesnt need any connection at all. Just cleans the file on your local directoy inside your project.

and `grails compile` to some extent might be needed if you don't have refresh the dependency successfully.

AS matter of fact older version for grails  after to 2.3.x require internet connectivity to download references that you have used in your `buildconfig.groovy` file. This lead to

Most of the time only `grails refresh dependency` from your `IDE /STS/GGTS` requires a connection to sync and download libraries from maven repertoires or some sort.

Any way, at least you need internet at first setting up your application, then not at all 
none of grails compile and grails clean doesn't require that.

Answer (score 1):

It requires an internet connection to download the `Grails` dependencies defined by the framework and in your `BuildConfig.groovy`. When start a new Grails app it will usually download these dependencies for you.

After that an internet connection is not required and you can work offline using

```
 grails -offline
```

as long you don't add new dependencies or you include external resources from a CDN.